# Using LESS variables in extended LESS file Magento 2

Tags: magento2, less, parent-child-theme, undefined-variable

I need to use **LESS Variables** in my extended LESS file in my theme.

I've this code in my **_extend.less** in this location `My_Magento\app\design\frontend\<My_Vendor>\<My_Theme>\web\i18n\fa_IR\css\source\_extend.less` :

```
@import '_rtl.less';
```

and in the **_rtl.less** file:

```
.myClass{
    background: @color_theme;
}
```

**Note that the @color_theme defined in the Parent Theme** in this location  `My_Magento\app\design\frontend\<Parent_Vendor>\<Parent_Theme>\web\css\_general.less`

**So when I run:**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**It will throw some errors like this:**

```
variable @color_theme is undefined in file C:/xampp7/htdocs/My_Magento/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/<My_Vendor>/<My_Theme>/fa_IR/css/source/_rtl.less in _rtl.less on line 20, column 15
```

It will happens for **any variable of any LESS Styles** included in Parent Theme or Modules etc. in my _extend.less theme file!

How can I use **LESS Variables** from **other sources** (Parent Theme or Modules LESS files) in my **_extend.less file**?

I'm using **Magento 2.1.9 with PHP 7.0.22 and XAMPP 3.2.2**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, That was for my parent theme! It has separated style in `yttheme.less` file that loaded after `style-l.less`, so when `style-l.less` is compiling with `_extend.less` files, it has not access to `yttheme.less` variables!

So I added a new style in my theme like `rtl.less` in **layout.xml** and **@import yttheme.less** there! Now I have access to that variables and Grunt run perfectly.

But a new problem arrived! I cant change **layout.xml** for my **locale(fa_IR)**!? and the changes affected for all locale!